# Loading View Via Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building an application that has a lot of graphs. I'd like to make the graphs load in via Ajax to reduce initial load time. This is what the current dashboard view looks like.

```
  <section class="container">
    <section class="row">
      <div class="span6 graph-container">
        <h3 class="box-header"><i class="icon-truck"></i>Service Levels</h3>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="/assets/loading.gif" class="loading" />
           <%= content_tag :div, "", id: "shipments-by-service-type", data: {shipments: @charts[:service_analysis][:spend_data]} %>
        </div>
      </div>
       <div class="span6 graph-container">
        <h3 class="box-header"><i class="icon-circle"></i>Weight Summary</h3>
        <div class="box">
          <%= content_tag :div, "", id: "weight-ranges", data: {weight: @charts[:weight_analysis][:spend_data]} %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="row">
      <div class="span6 graph-container">
        <h3 class="box-header"><i class="icon-road"></i>Zone Summary</h3>
        <div class="box">
          <%= content_tag :div, "", id: "weight-groups-zones", data: {zone: @charts[:zone_analysis][:spend_data]} %>
        </div>
      </div>
       <div class="span6 graph-container">
        <h3 class="box-header"><i class="icon-time"></i>Spend Over Time</h3>
        <div class="box">
          <%= content_tag :div, "", id: "shipping-trends", data: {trends: @charts[:shipping_trends][:spend_data]} %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </section>
```

My current thought is to be a controller called `charts_controller.rb` This would contain all of the logic for each of the charts and have a view or partial the corresponds with a method and then load in via Ajax each one of those views.

```
class ChartsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :company_id

  def service_level
   #logic for service_level graph
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html
     format.js
   end
  end

end
```

for example 
I'm new to working with Ajax inside of rails and am not sure how to go about doing this. Does this approach make sense?

Comment: You mean the area for the graphs would be initiallt empty, then a user trigger some click on some button and the graps appear?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm thinking, show a loading gif while waiting for them to appear.

Answer (score 1):

You could "draw" the charts in a partial on the server side. If you are using jQuery then you could use the jQuery.load function:

```
$('#graph-div').load('/my_restful_route');
```

The controller would have something like:

```
render partial: 'chart_partial'
```

Comment: I set this up and it's work, but the div keeps reloading it's self. Thoughts to why that might be happeing?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you have the jQuery load code inside of some jQuery event listener that is getting called more than once. I would just put the code right inside the document ready: $(document).ready(function () { $('#graph-div').load('/my_restful_route'); });